# Unity cooldown implementation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement cooldowns in my project in Unity, while this code seems to make sense, it doesn't work. The code that's posted is an all-around basic movement script.

I tried doing something with a `cooldown -=time.deltatime`, but that didn't seem to work. I've been trying several methods, but none seem to work.

The code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float cooldown = 0;
    public float actualcooldown = 3f;
    public bool isCooldown = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.G))
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.B))
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Translate(6f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Translate(-6f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && cooldown <= 0) {
            transform.Translate(0f, 20f * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
            isCooldown = true;
            while (isCooldown == true)
            {
                coolDownhappening();
            }
        }
    }

    public void coolDownhappening()
    {
        cooldown = actualcooldown;
        cooldown -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (cooldown <= 0)
        {
            cooldown = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please [edit] your question and describe the desired and actual behavior? "does not work" is not a helpful problem description and your question may be closed as "unclear". See also [ask].

Comment: What do *you* mean by "cooldown?"

Comment: The statement `cooldown = actualcooldown;` executes every frame, so your time adjustment does basically nothing. Your `Update()` blocks the game thread until you've done all of the cooldown stuff. You'll need a coroutine for this. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

You do

```
 while (isCooldown == true)
 {
     coolDownhappening();
 }
```

But you **never** change `isCoolddown` anywhere!

Also as was already mentioned in the comments you do **not** want to use `while` in the `Update` method at all, at least not in this usecase! This will freeze the entire mainthread for the given cooldown time - or in your case forever!

---

There are a lot of other issues in your code so let's go step by step:

- `Input.GetKey` is true **every frame** while they given key is pressed. However, it makes no sense and only causes unecessary overhead to repeatedly set the materials color to the same value as long as a button stays pressed. What you rather want to do is apply it once.

  → rather use `Input.GetKeyDown` for these!
- `GetComponent` is a quite expensive call. You should **not** repeadedly use `GetComponent<Renderer>()` but rather store the reference **once** and re-use it later

  ```
  // most efficient is always to already reference this via the Inspector
  [SerializeField] private Renderer _renderer;

  // alternatively get it on runtime
  private void Awake()
  {
      if(!_renderer) _rednerer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
  }
  ```

  and then later use

  ```
  private void Update()
  {
      if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
      {
          _renderer.material.color = Color.red;
      }

      ...
  }
  ```
- Your moving part is actually fine. To make it slightly more readable I would however actually rather do something like

  ```
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
  {
      transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 6f * Time.deltaTime);
  }
  else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
  {
      transform.Translate(Vector3.left * 6f * Time.deltaTime);
  }
  ```

  also note the `else` here. Depends on your needs of course but usually you want contrary buttons exclusive.
- Finally to the real deal: You actually want to have a jump method with a cooldown here.

  First here you did it the other way round: `Input.GetKeyDown` is called only exactly **once** namely in the frame when the key went down. So your object "jumps" `20 * 1/FPS` which for 60 FPS is always about `0.33`. You probably rather wanted to move a certain distance upwards over multiple frames. After a certain height is reached, activate a cooldown.

  As mentioned in the comments one *can* do this in `Update` using a timer but usually this makes the code a bit messy. Rather use a Coroutine:

  ```
  private bool _canJump;

  private void Update()
  {
      ...

      // _canJump is cheaper to check so check it first
      if (_canJump && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
      {
          StartCoroutine(JumpRoutine());
      }
  }

  private IEnumerator JumpRoutine()
  {
      // avoid concurrent routines
      if(!_canJump) yield break;
      // disable jumping
      _canJump = false;

      // Now it really depends on what you actually want to do 
      // and how your object should move now
      // you might e.g. want something like
      var jumpedHeight = 0f;
      while(jumpedHeight < 20f)
      {
          var jumpThisFrame = Vector3.up * 6f * Time.deltaTime;
          transform.Translate(jumpThisFrame);

          // important now! yield tells Unity to "pause" here,
          // render this frame, and continue from here int he next frame
          // without the yield statements this would again freeze your game until
          // the exit condition is fulfilled!
          yield return null;
      }

      // After reaching the target height this waits for 3 seconds but keeps on rendering meanwhile
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(actualcooldown);

      // after the cooldown allow next jump
      _canJump = true;
  }
  ```

Comment: I tried your code, "waitforseconds" near the end is missing.

Comment: maybe because a `d` was missing on my side? ;)